# About the limit $L=\lim_{a_n\to4}\left(\frac{2a_n-1}{4-a_n}+\frac{3{a_n}^2+1}{{a_n}^2-a_n-12}\right)$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Find the limit $$L=\lim_{a_n\to4}\left(\dfrac{2a_n-1}{4-a_n}+\dfrac{3{a_n}^2+1}{{a_n}^2-a_n-12}\right)$$ I don't seem to understand why we cannot write our limit as: $$L=\lim_{a_n\to4}\left(\dfrac{2a_n-1}{4-a_n}\right)+\lim_{a_n\to4}\left(\dfrac{3a_n^2+1}{a_n^2-a_n-12}\right)=\left[\dfrac{7}{0}\right]+\left[\dfrac{49}{0}\right]=[\infty+\infty]=\infty$$

I am familiar with the way that we are supposed to use to solve the problem (using the common denominator and etc.). I would just like to understand where my mistake is and why my solution isn't an option when dealing with such problems.

Comment: You can only split a sum of limits like what you have done if the limit of each summand exists. In your case, the limit of neither summand exists.

Comment: Incidentally, the limit is equal $3/7$ (and hence not $\infty$) once you have rewritten your sequence with common denominator and cancelled common factors.

Comment: @MathsMatador, can you clarify for me why the limits does not exist?

Comment: What I mean by "the limit exists" here is that there is a real number that is equal to the limit. So for example, the limit of $\frac{2a_n-1}{4-a_n}$ as $a_n \to 4$ does not exist because as you get closer and closer to $4$, the sequence blows up towards infinity, which is not a real number.

Comment: @MathsMatador, so for us to split a sum of limits like what I have done we need the limits of both summands be real numbers, not infinities? Why is that the case?

Comment: Well what does it really mean to add infinity with another infinity? How do you perform basic algebraic manipulations with infinity? Infinity is not a number, in this case it is merely a symbol that encodes the information of "does not exist in the set of real numbers". So for splitting a sum of limits like that, the idea is that you must already know what you have obtained after splitting the limit, or rather, the summands can be summed in the first place. This cannot be done for infinities.

Answer (score 1):

Your way fails because the sum leads to an indeterminate form ($\infty-\infty$), indeed

- for $a_n \to 4^+$

$$\dfrac{2a_n-1}{4-a_n} \to -\infty$$

$$\dfrac{3{a_n}^2+1}{{a_n}^2-a_n-12}=\dfrac{3{a_n}^2+1}{(a_n-4)(a_n+3)} \to \infty$$

- for $a_n \to 4^-$

$$\dfrac{2a_n-1}{4-a_n} \to \infty$$

$$\dfrac{3{a_n}^2+1}{{a_n}^2-a_n-12}=\dfrac{3{a_n}^2+1}{(a_n-4)(a_n+3)} \to -\infty$$

Answer (score -1):

You can rewrite it as:  $\dfrac{3a_n^2+1}{(a_n-4)(a_n+3)} - \dfrac{(2a_n-1)(a_n+3)}{(a_n-4)(a_n+3)}=\dfrac{(a_n-4)(a_n-1)}{(a_n-4)(a_n+3)}=\dfrac{a_n-1}{a_n+3}\to \dfrac{4-1}{4+3}=\dfrac{3}{7}$.

Comment: I didn't downvote but note that the OP is asking where its method fails.

Comment: I'm referring to the part: "*I am familiar with the way that we are supposed to use to solve the problem (using the common denominator and etc.)*"